# How add schema.org properities with Zend framework?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

I want to add with Zend farmework headMeta (the problem is: how create "itemprop"): 
- google generator+html5 checked in http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Title of your content">
<meta itemprop="description" content="This would be a description of the content your users are sharing">
<meta itemprop="image" content="ourimage.jpg">
```

Edit:
I want to do that for google plus:http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I see that you have marked your question as "html5". I had the similar issues two days ago. You can't use "itemprop" in HTML5. Instead you could use meta "name" like this:

// here $key is like "description, and value -> "Title of your content"
$this->headMeta()->appendName($key, $value);

If you want to do this for facebook that's the way to go in order for the HTML5 validator not to throw many errors.

Comment: thanks,please see my edit. google generator generate the code in my question when include html5.

Comment: Can you give reference why "itemprop" can be used in html5 valid page?itemprop is html5 valid

Comment: I am sorry. My mistake. In my case it was not valid not because of the itemprop, but because I was trying to use the OpenGraph protocol.